# Slow loop performance while updating data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, recursion, for-loop, while-loop

In my winform application, I have 2 datatables, both contains 37000 rows. Table 1 has 171 columns and Table 2 has 4 columns. A While loop runs to update values in Table 1 from Table 2 for 4 columns. A For loop runs inside While twice to update values. It takes more than 5 min to do so. which i think should be a task of 5 seconds.

Columns being updated are:

> Int64 - 1 Columns
>
> String - 1 Columns
>
> Boolean - 1 Columns
>
> Date - 1 Columns

Can someone give idea what may be causing this issue?

```
        While lintRowCounter < ldtCurrentData.Rows.Count
            ldrCurrentDataRow = ldtCurrentData(lintRowCounter)
            For Each lobjDataEntity As DataEntities In lstDataEntities
                ldrCurrentDataRow(lobjDataEntity.SourceName) = ldtPositionData(lintRowCounter).Item(lobjDataEntity.SourceName)
                If ldtCurrentData.Columns.Contains(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrFormulaColSuffix) Then
                    ldrCurrentDataRow(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrFormulaColSuffix) = ldtPositionData(lintRowCounter).Item(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrFormulaColSuffix)
                End If
                If ldtCurrentData.Columns.Contains(mstrSOFColPrefix + lobjDataEntity.SourceName) Then
                    ldrCurrentDataRow(mstrSOFColPrefix + lobjDataEntity.SourceName) = ldtPositionData(lintRowCounter).Item(mstrSOFColPrefix + lobjDataEntity.SourceName)
                End If
                If ldtCurrentData.Columns.Contains(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrSourceDateColSuffix) Then
                    ldrCurrentDataRow(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrSourceDateColSuffix) = ldtPositionData(lintRowCounter).Item(lobjDataEntity.SourceName + mstrSourceDateColSuffix)
                End If
            Next
            lintRowCounter += 1
        End While
```

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with entity framework, but wouldn't this create 74,000 individual database connections?

Comment: Datatables are disconncted in nature in .NET, hence there won't be any connection.

Comment: Can someone please provide suggestions/comments on that. It's quite urgent. Let me know if enough information is provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you already know the column names, why wouldn't you refer to them directly instead of doing an IF-CONTAINS?  Checking for the column name that way seems expensive.  Also you should consider putting code like this `mstrSOFColPrefix + lobjDataEntity.SourceName` into a single variable so it's building that string over and over.  String concats are expensive; hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think to do would be to batch your update.  (i.e. Instead of 37,000 all at once, process 2,000 at a time so the program doesn't overload.)

Try this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbbwt18a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0

Or this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Batches are not going to help in my case. I need all of them to updated in one go.

Comment: That's all I can think of, sorry :(.  I know I used batching on a database of users I had for a program once.  I peaked at 11,230 users and had over 3,000 logged in at any given time so to keep the database current I used batches of 500 every second.  Try MSDN forums.